# Error when summing the content of params dynamic[]

Tags: c#, dynamic, parameters

I want to make a function that will return the sum ( concatenation for string ) of any number of argument I pass.
Below function works well with string but **throwing error for other data types ( int, double...etc)**
What am I missing?

Error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:
  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
   'System.Console.WriteLine(string, params object[])' and 
   'System.Console.WriteLine(char[])'
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )
```

Code:

```cs
public static dynamic sumfunction(params dynamic[] arr)
{
    dynamic res=null;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.Length;i++)
    {
        res += arr[i];
    }

    return res;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dynamic vv=sumfunction("my","name");
    Console.WriteLine(vv);

    vv = sumfunction(5,6,7);
    Console.WriteLine(vv);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [ask]. In particular, you should put details of the errors you're seeing into your question.

Comment: What error is it throwing? My guess is that you can't add an `int` to `null`.

Comment: Your method isn't throwing - `Console.WriteLine` is, because the value is null, and that's an ambiguous call.

Comment: Jon Skeet already gave the answer. Note that also without `dynamic`, you have `null + "my" + "name"` gives `"myname"`, and `null + 5 + 6 + 7` gives `null` (of compile-time type `int?` when you do not use `dynamic`; when you do use `dynamic`, `null` has no type). To avoid exceptions, you can use `Console.WriteLine((object)vv);`. It will write an empty string followed by a new line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code is throwing an exception in `Console.WriteLine(vv);` because `vv` is null, and the call becomes ambiguous in the same way that this code does:

```cs
// error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
// 'Console.WriteLine(char[])' and 'Console.WriteLine(string)'
Console.WriteLine(null);
```

So why is `vv` null in the second case? Because you started with null, and added to it. I suspect the binder is converting both `null` and the non-null integer to `int?` and then performing addition using the lifted addition operator. That reasoning is only an educated guess, but certainly the result is null. (You can check that with normal null checks on the result.)

The fix is to start with "the first element in the array" for the addition rather than with null, and only return null if the input array is either null or empty (or if a real addition ends up with null - which it could do if null is one of the elements in the array). You can also fix `Console.WriteLine` causing a problem even in that case by using `object` as the type of the local variable receiving the result, rather than `dynamic`. Here's an example with all that fixed, as well as using more idiomatic names:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static dynamic Sum(params dynamic[] arr)
    {
        if (arr == null || arr.Length == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        dynamic result = arr[0];
        foreach (var item in arr.Skip(1))
        {
            result += item;
        }

        return result;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object sum = Sum("my", "name");
        Console.WriteLine(sum);

        sum = Sum(5, 6, 7);
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        Console.WriteLine(null);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
myname
18
```

Comment: "*I suspect the binder is converting both null and the non-null integer to int? and then performing addition using the lifted addition operator*" -- looks like you're correct, the expression it generates is `null + Convert($arg1)`, where `Convert` is a conversion to `Nullable<Int32>`